# Save and overwrite files in the resource folder possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Do anyone know if it is possible to save and overwrite files to the "Resources" folder which I create for my resources before sending the app to Apple? So I know how to get files from there, but I'm not sure how to save and overwrite for e.g. a pdf file from a specific url to this folder, when the App is on the Iphone.
Thanks for your answers!=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make any edits in the Resource folder after you app is shipped,It's read-only,use Documents/Caches/tmp instead.